# C - Update a variable value and update instantly on terminal

Tags: c, server

I'm not sure i've even worded correctly what i wanted to say.

I'm developing a client/server chat in C. When you connect, the servers sends the client a list of available rooms, showing how many users are in each room.

Something like this:

```
1 - Videogames [0/10]
2 - Cinema [2/10]
```

The way i've implemented this is by creating a Room struct, which contains a variable called 'howMany', that gets incremented whenever a client chooses that room.

Thing is, since the server sends the client a buffer like this:

```
sprintf(send_buffer, "1 - Videogames [%d/10]", room1->howMany)
```

If the client is waiting on this page for a couple of minutes, there could be 7/10 users in the first room, 10/10 in the second, but he will still see the same output i've posted before.

Any way i could fix this? I already tried 'sending the buffer with the rooms again everytime howMany gets incremented', but it gives me problems and I don't want to print again the output.

If there's a way, i would want that number to change 'on the go'.

Comment: dealing with terminals this way is the road to madness, you should look into something that deals with this for you like curses/ncurses ...

Comment: @GradyPlayer Little hard to do over network though.

Comment: Is this school work with limitations, or your own project where you can use any libraries etx you want?

Comment: why wouldn't curses work over a network?

Comment: Also, for network code, operating system matters greatly. Please add a tag with this info.

Comment: Actually, following the up on the comment by @GradyPlayer, you could use curses in the client, and then come up with a protocol that doesn't send the full screen but only the latest status. Like for example if the counter for one chat-room is updated, the server sends an update containing an identifier for the chat-room and the new counter. Then the client receives the update and update its own UI to reflect that single change.

Comment: Yes, for sane solution, you need a protocol which sends only the data, and then client shows it as it sees fit. Or, a simple protocol where server sends text lines like `row,column,any text until newline` and client is very dumb, understands only this simple protocol.

Comment: It's a school project, so i don't have that many options. So, as i imagined, it's not something i can do right now lol. Thanks for your answers, though!

Comment: Alternatively, you can provide feedback when attempting to join a room. The console text  was correct _at the time_, and you can simply inform them that `Room is full! [10/10 people]` followed by re-listing the room populations

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard Linux terminal, you can use escape sequences to interact with it. Usually you should not do this, because it is not portable. You can find all of them on the [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) page (or [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html).

In you case you want to do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

update_line(int line_no, char* format, ...) {
    printf("\033[%d;0H", line_no);
    printf("\033[2K"); // clear the line the cursor is in
    va_list l;
    va_start(l, format);
    vprintf(format, l);
    va_end(l);
}
```